# How can I send a message to all connected TCP clients?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, tcp, rust-tokio

I have written a TCP-server which checks when a user leaves. It should then send a message to chat (all clients) that a user left the chat.

I wrote this code:
client:

```
use {
    std::{io::BufRead, thread},
    tokio::{
        io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader},
        net::TcpStream,
        sync::mpsc,
    },
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();

    let (reader, mut writer) = stream.split();

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);

    let mut nickname: String = String::new();
    let mut response = " ".to_string();

    while response.trim() != "200" {
        nickname.clear();
        if response != " " {
            println!("Already exist in a chat");
        }

        println!("{}", "Enter your nickname: ");
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut nickname).unwrap();

        let request = format!("/register){}", nickname);

        writer.write_all(request.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
        response.clear();
        reader.read_line(&mut response).await.unwrap();
    }

    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(10);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut stdin = std::io::stdin().lock();
        loop {
            let mut line = String::new();
            stdin.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
            tx.blocking_send(line).unwrap();
        }
    });

    loop {
        let mut line = String::new();
        tokio::select! {
            result = reader.read_line(&mut line) => {
                result.unwrap();
                println!("{:?}", line);



                let mut split2 = line.splitn(2, ':');

                let author = split2.next().unwrap();
                let msg = split2.next().unwrap();


                print!("){}:{}", author, msg);



            }

            result = rx.recv() => {
                let line_write = result.unwrap();


                if line_write.trim().len() > 0 {
                    let output: String;

                    output = format!("){}: {}", nickname.trim(), line_write);

                    writer.write_all(output.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();


                } else {
                    println!("message is too short");
                }



            }
        }
    }
}
```

server:

```
use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader},
    net::TcpListener,
    sync::{broadcast, Mutex},
};

use std::{
    collections::{HashMap, HashSet},
    sync::Arc,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tcp_listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();
    let nicknames: Arc<Mutex<HashSet<String>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashSet::new()));
    let addr_nickname: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

    let (tx, _rx) = broadcast::channel(10);

    loop {
        let (mut socket, addr) = tcp_listener.accept().await.unwrap();

        let tx: broadcast::Sender<(String, std::net::SocketAddr)> = tx.clone();
        let mut rx: broadcast::Receiver<(String, std::net::SocketAddr)> = tx.subscribe();
        let nicknames: Arc<Mutex<HashSet<String>>> = Arc::clone(&nicknames);
        let addr_nickname: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>> = Arc::clone(&addr_nickname);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let (reader, mut writer) = socket.split();

            let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);

            let mut line = String::new();

            loop {
                tokio::select! {
                    result = reader.read_line(&mut line) => {
                        match result {
                            Ok(_) => {

                                tx.send((line.clone(), addr)).unwrap();
                                line.clear();
                            },
                            Err(e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::ConnectionReset => {
                                println!("Connection was reset by the client: {:?}, by {:?}", e, addr);
                                let mut nicknames = nicknames.lock().await;
                                let mut addr_nickname = addr_nickname.lock().await;
                                let nickname_to_delete = addr_nickname.get(&addr.to_string()).unwrap();
                                line = format!("/left){} has left", &nickname_to_delete);
                                nicknames.remove(nickname_to_delete);
                                addr_nickname.remove(&addr.to_string());


                                println!("{:?}, {:?}", nicknames, addr_nickname);

                                tx.send((line.clone(), addr)).unwrap();

                                line.clear();

                                break;
                            },
                            Err(e) => {
                                println!("An unexpected error occurred: {:?}", e);
                            },
                        }


                    }
                    result = rx.recv() => {

                        let (msg, other_addr) = result.unwrap();


                        println!("{:?}, {:?}", msg, other_addr);

                        let mut split = msg.splitn(2, ')');

                        let command = split.next().unwrap();
                        let nickname = split.next().unwrap();


                        if command == "/register" && addr == other_addr {

                            let mut nicknames = nicknames.lock().await;
                            let mut addr_nickname = addr_nickname.lock().await;
                            println!("{:?}, {}, {:?}", nicknames, nickname, addr_nickname);
                            if nicknames.contains(nickname.trim()) {
                                writer.write_all(b"406\n").await.unwrap();
                            } else {


                                nicknames.insert(nickname.trim().to_string());
                                addr_nickname.insert(addr.to_string(), nickname.trim().to_string());
                                writer.write_all(b"200\n").await.unwrap();
                                println!("{:?}", nicknames);
                            }
                        } else if command == "/users" && addr == other_addr {
                            let addr_nickname = addr_nickname.lock().await;
                            if addr_nickname.is_empty() {
                                writer.write_all(b"No users found\n").await.unwrap();
                            } else {
                                let users: String = addr_nickname.values().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>().join(", ");
                                match writer.write_all(users.as_bytes()).await {
                                    Ok(_) => println!("Response sent successfully"),
                                    Err(e) => println!("Failed to send response: {}", e),
                                }
                            }
                        } else if addr != other_addr && command != "/register" && command != "/users" {
                            println!("{:?}, {:?}, {}, {:?}, {:?}", command, nickname, command=="/register", addr, other_addr);

                            writer.write_all(msg.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();

                        }






                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But it doesn`t work, I do not receive any message about users leaving

Still the message about leaving is received only after some user sends a new message after someone who left.
[first user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUdtM.png)
[second user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA8cs.png)

Comment: Please create a [mre] instead of dumping your whole codebase with mostly irrelevant code/imports. Also please provide text (your chat logs) as text instead of images.

Comment: @cafce25 wdym? it`s fully reproducible, just make 2 rust projects, 1 for client and other for server, copy first and second code blocks, and type cargo run.

Comment: It's not *minimal* though. `colored`, `rusty_audio`, `regex`, `rand` and possibly more are not needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1):

solution was very simple haha, i readed article about tcp, the problem is

```
line = format!("/left){} has left", &nickname_to_delete);
```

this line doesn't have \n and because of that, message isn't send.
so solution is:

```
line = format!("/left){} has left\n", &nickname_to_delete);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEwRm.png)

Comment: Because of that the message isn't read by anything that expects a line. It's sent all right. And that has nothing to do with TCP: it is a property of the APIs you are using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).